# Make a top ten of the best players using Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase Database and I'm struggling with this problem. What I want to achieve is: show a top ten of the best players based on their "hits". I know I could use firebase queries but I don't know how to use them.

[image]

```
Query mquery =
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("player")
                            .orderByChild("hits");

            mquery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        UserInformation score=postSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);

                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) postSnapshot.getValue();

                        Log.d("test"," values is " + score.getHits());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Every time I run this code I get the next error:

```
Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
```

Comment: Read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#orderby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missing two things:

1. a `limitToLast(10)` so that you get the 10 highest scores only
2. use `.orderByChild("easy/hits")`, since that's where the value is stored

So:

```
Query mquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("player")
                        .orderByChild("easy/hits")
                        .limitToLast(10);
```

Note that a `Map` is inherently unordered, so not a good structure to keep an *ordered* list in. You'll want to use some `List` structure for that.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
        String name = postSnapshot.child("easy/name").getValue(String.class);
        names.add(0, name);
    }
}
```

You'll note that I call `names.add(0, name)`. This ensures that the results end up in the list in *descending* order, like you'd expect on a leaderboard.

Comment: Woops, that should be `add()`. Let me fix that. `add(index, object)` is a method on `List`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But using `names.add(0, name);` doesn't mean that you add the `name` on the same index `0` on each iteration? So in the end having a list with only a single item?

Comment: From the docs: "Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). **Shifts the element currently at that position** (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)."

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank, completely understood! Voted up.